# Android apk file components have incorrect timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am generating an android apk using gradle system from command line. Although the generated apk has correct timestamp(i.e modified time), apk components (for eg classes.dex) have wrong timestamp - Fri, Nov 30 1979 00:00:00. 
What can be the possible cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you paste the path where you are seeing the `classes.dex` file. Are you making a debug build ?

Comment: Yes, I am generating an apk in debug mode by using following command : ./gradlew assembleDebug. I am checking the classes.dex files by simply extracting apk componets by archive manger. Path of the generated dex files is test.apk_FILES/classes.dex

Comment: try `clean` before `assembleDebug`. All your build artifacts will be deleted and built again

Comment: @Dibzmania Still the same issue persists.

Comment: This is still a problem in 2020. Some utils that read APKs as zips will choke on them now because they aren't _really_ valid zip entries.